# predict() function in R is not providing prediction in R console

Tags: r, statistics, cart

My training data has 87620 rows and 5 columns. My test data has the same number of rows and columns. When I use a CART model to predict the "Defaults" (that is the target variable), my model works and provides me with predictions.

When I use a validation data set that has 6 columns and only 19561 rows, and does not have the Defaults variable, and then proceed to use the

```
View(validationsetpreds.CART3.3x)
```

I get the attached picture

[Validationsetpreds Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sifj9.png)

And when I perform the same command using the test data set I get the following [Testsetpreds Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKh4m.png)

```
set.seed(123)

loans_training$Default <- as.factor(loans_training$Default)#Make the default variable categorical
loans_test$Default <- as.factor(loans_test$Default)#Make the default variable categorical

loans_training$term <- as.factor(loans_training$term)
loans_test$term <- as.factor(loans_test$term)

#Standardize datasets
library(psych)
library(caret)
preprocess.train.z <- preProcess(loans_training[1:5], method = c("center", "scale"))
preprocess.train.z
loans_train.z <- predict(preprocess.train.z,loans_training[1:5])

describe(loans_train.z)
View(loans_train.z)
summary(loans_train.z$Default)
preprocess.test.z <- preProcess(loans_test[1:5], method = c("center", "scale"))
preprocess.test.z
loans_test.z <- predict(preprocess.test.z,loans_test[1:5])

describe(loans_test.z)
View(loans_test.z)

summary(loans_train.z$Default)
(22417 * 2.3) + 22417

#Resampling subroutine
rare.record.indices <- which(loans_train.z$Default == "1")
rare.indices.resampled <- sample(x = rare.record.indices,size = 51559, replace = TRUE)
rare.records.resampled <- loans_train.z[rare.indices.resampled,]
loans_train.3.3x <- rbind(loans_train.z, rare.records.resampled)
table(loans_train.3.3x$Default)

#Develop 3.3x CART model
TC <- trainControl(method = "CV", number = 10)
fit.CART.3.3x <- train(Default ~ ., data = loans_train.3.3x, method = "rpart", trControl = TC)
fit.CART.3.3x$resample
testsetpreds.CART3.3x <- predict(fit.CART.3.3x,loans_test.z)
table(loans_test.z$Default, testsetpreds.CART3.3x)
testsetpreds.CART3.3x


#Predictions
set.seed(123)

loans_validation$grade <- as.character(loans_validation$grade)#Make the grade variable categorical

loans_validation$term <- as.factor(loans_validation$term)#Make the term variable categorical

loans_validation$Index <- as.factor(loans_validation$Index)#Make the Index variable categorical
#Standardize dataset
library(psych)
library(caret)
preprocess.validation.z <- preProcess(loans_validation[1:6], method = c("center", "scale"))
preprocess.validation.z
loans_validation.z <- predict(preprocess.validation.z,loans_validation[1:6])

#Predict Defaults using Cart
validationsetpreds.CART3.3x <- predict(fit.CART.3.3x,loans_validation.z)
View(validationsetpreds.CART3.3x)
```

Any help would be greatly appreaciated :)

How would I apply this to the validation data set?

Comment: Can you please use `head`, `str` and other functions to output results in question instead of providing images?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never posted here before so I don't know what the proper procedure is.